# Trim is not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

trim() javascript function not working in IE7 however it' working fine in all other version and all browser. what should be issue with IE7 or how i can resolve this?

```
$("#Email").val().trim()
```

[image: IE7 gives error]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

IE doesn't support `String.prototype.trim()` until IE9.

It looks like you're using jQuery, so you can use `$.trim()` instead.

```
$.trim($("#Email").val())
```

Comment: thanks it's working fine in IE7 now however$("#Email").val().trim() was working on IE9 (probably in all above IE7)

Comment: @ArunRana: Yes, IE9 works. I didn't think IE8 had `.trim()` though. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

The `val()` method doesn't always return a `string`.  If the selected item is an option it can return an array which doesn't support `trim`.  Have you checked the type of `val()` to see if it's actually a `string`?

Note: As others have pointed out `trim` isn't supported on IE7 even if this is a `string`.  Need at least IE9.